# Localhost refused to connect for Spring Boot Application Using Eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-boot, localhost

```
 pom.xml file:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>





    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>






    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>




</project>
```

java file 1:

```
package springWaterProj;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

java file 2:

```
package springWaterProj;



import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class HelloController {


    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHi() {
        return "hi"; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Solution 1: Terminate Process

```
A simple solution is to terminate the process (in IDE) and clean and rebuild project.
```

Click on RED button to terminate a process

[image: Click on RED button to terminate process]

---

> Solution 2: Change Port

```
Change the port 
server.port=8088 # Server HTTP port.
```

---

> Solution 3: Kill Process using cmd

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<yourPortNumber>
taskkill /PID <typeyourPIDhere> /F
```

Comment: @abby Welcome, please accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. How do I accept the answer?

Comment: Below vote count you can see right mark just click on it, Thank you

Comment: I am still getting this error.  I am unable to connect to my own spring boot api via curl/postman even though it says port 3333 has started on Tomcat when I run the application.  When I run nmap on 127.0.0.1 (loopback network card,) I do not see the port as open.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not complete. If you are getting error like below that means port `8080` is already being used.

```
The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

In this case you can either stop application that is running on thisport or simply use different port. On your `application.properties`  file you can define port as

```
server.port=8181
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think that is the reason. I closed and reopened eclipse and it works again. Is there any button on eclipse I can use to kill the port? also how do I find the application.properties file? Thank you

Comment: When you create a spring boot app, there should be 'application.properties' file. If not you can create new one. You can kill the process running on specific port. You might want to google or post a new question.  If my solution solved your problem please marked my answer as correct.